# Animation: Object following path slows down at end

Tags: animation

I have a light object following a Bezier circle around a text object.

When I play the animation inside Blender I notice that the object slows down starting around frame 90ish.

I also would like to know why, when in repeat mode (meaning the animation keeps repeating from frame 1 tot end) the object halts for a split second.

Can both "issues" be solved?

I would like the object not to slow down at the end and if possible when repeating I would like to see a smooth motion.

I follow this tut and as you can see the light keeps going in 1 smooth motion.

https://youtu.be/jLqD2_cVdQM?t=201

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all keyframes, then press V on the timeline and choose vector (or T > Interpolation > Linear). Then your animation speed is constant.

[image]

to have a "smooth" animation without the split just select the last keyframe

[image]

then press G 1

[image]

and enjoy your smooth animation:

[image]

Comment: or T > Interpolation > Linear

Comment: updated my answer ;)

Comment: Thanks. Please also add to your answer that pressing V needs to be done on both keyframes. (at least for me in V3.0.0)

Comment: you just have to select all keyframes...than one time v is enough....

Comment: Yeah thats what I meant :-) @Chris